# Correct placement of UIImageView in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

When attempting to place a `UIImageView(UIImage)` into a `UIBarButtonItem` on a `UINavigationBar`, the image gets placed in the middle of the bar and also has wide fields covering the entire bar. So, doesn't look like a small button on the left.

I've tried various tricks with frame resizing, contentMode settings.

The below code is from my View Controller, which is part of the Navigation Controller stack. Added this image into Assets:
http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-hd-bike-ktm-bike-png-500.png
 for testing, named it bike.png and used it in UIImage below.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "bike")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.backgroundColor = .blue //for debugging
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
  }
```

The expected result would be to have the image of the motorbike in the left, rather than in the middle. Also, no empty fields to the left and to the right (highlighted in blue for debugging) of the image.

**EXPECTED (drew up in Paintbrush)**:

[image]

**REALITY**:

[image]

Comment: You need to add a width constraint to limit the width of the image view, I think.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up resolving as:

```imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up resolving as:

```
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!).isActive = true
```